# Why can't I set a file type variable in the redux toolkit state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to set a file inside a slice with redux-toolkit but it doesn't work.

First, here is my slice file

```html
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

export const assignorsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "assignors",
  initialState: {
    list: [],
    assignorFileSignToUpdate: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    getAssignorsList: (state) => {
      return state.list
    },
    setAssignorsList: (state, action) => {
      state.list = action.payload
    },
    addAssignor: (state, action) => {
      state.list.push(action.payload)
    },
    toggleAssignor: (state, action) => {
      const rut = action.payload
      const assignor = state.list.find((assignor) => {
        return assignor.rut === rut
      })
      assignor.active = !assignor.active
    },
    setAssignorFileSignToUpdate: (state, action) => {
      state.assignorFileSignToUpdate = action.payload
      console.log(
        " ~ file: assignors.js ~ line 28 ~ action.payload",
        action.payload
      )
      console.log(
        " ~ file: assignors.js ~ line 29 ~ state.assignorFileSignToUpdate",
        state.assignorFileSignToUpdate
      )
    },
    getAssignorFileSignToUpdate: (state) => {
      return state.assignorFileSignToUpdate
    },
  },
})

// export actions
export const {
  setAssignorsList,
  addAssignor,
  toggleAssignor,
  getAssignorsList,
  setAssignorFileSignToUpdate,
  getAssignorFileSignToUpdate,
} = assignorsSlice.actions

export default assignorsSlice.reducer
```

The problem is in the `setAssignorFileSignToUpdate` action, I logged the payload and the state variable. The payload and the state in the console.log are correct, but the redux chrome extensión shows the `assignorFileSignToUpdate` variable with an empty object (see the image).

[console and redux screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzOgI.png)

In the slice file the `assignorFileSignToUpdate` variable is a file (the console.log shows it), but in the redux chrome extension is not, and when I call the useSelector to see this variable is an empty object too.

I don't know why this is happening, if you guys know the mistake I made or a way to fix it I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.